# I can't send data to datatable with function

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

Datatable data disappears when I click a column to sort
I'm writing data to a table with Ajax, but it's not working correctly. I am able to return the data as JSON and show it in the table, but when I click a column to sort the data, all of the data in the table disappears immediately and I end up with a blank table.

View:

```
<html>
  <table id="stokDataTable" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Barcode</th>
        <th>Ürün ad</th>
        <th>Ürün Fiyat</th>
        <th>Ürün Miktar</th>
        <th>Ürün Grup</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    </tbody>
  </table>
</html>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#stokDataTable').DataTable(StokListe())
});

function StokListe(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '../DataTable/Liste',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            json_object = $.parseJSON(data);

            for (var i = 0; i < json_object.length; i++) {
                $('#stokDataTable').append('<tr>' +
                  '<td>' + json_object[i].Barcode + '</td>' +
                  '<td>' + json_object[i].UrunAd + '</td>' +
                  '<td>' + json_object[i].UrunFiyat + '</td>' +
                  '<td>' + json_object[i].UrunAdet + '</td>' +
                  '<td>' + json_object[i].GrupIsmi + '</td>' +
                  '</tr>');
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("again");
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Liste()
{
    SqlConnection baglanti = system.baglan();
    SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from stok s left join StokGrup sg on s.UrunGrup=sg.GrupKodu order by s.UrunGrup", baglanti);
    cmd.Fill(dataTable, "liste");
    var rapor = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable.Tables["liste"]);
    return Json(rapor);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the datatable is rendering the data correctly and only the sort and search are not working?  Do you see the sort buttons and search filter textbox, or are they missing?  Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: datatable comes as it should. No error appears on the console screen. display data; If I do like 
<th>12345</th>
<th>random</th>
<th>1125,5</th>
<th>15</th>
<th>drink</th>
 everything works.

Comment: So if all you do is change `<th>Barcode</th><th>Ürün ad</th><th>Ürün Fiyat</th><th>Ürün Miktar</th><th>Ürün Grup</th>` to what you posted in your comment, that solves the problem?  What version of DataTables are you using?

Comment: ı can only read manually entered data. but the number of data in the database may be uncertain. boostrap 5.0 --- jquery.datatable 1.10.15

Comment: I tried reproducing your problem.  I can see the data in the table, but when I click a column to sort the data disappears.  I'm not sure how to fix that, but would like to clarify the question for others.  Is this the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, I totally agree.

Comment: For anyone needing to reproduce OP's problem to provide assistance, use this instead of the SQL code to simulate the database connection and get data: `var dataTable = new DataSet("myDataSet"); var dt = dataTable.Tables; dt.Clear(); dt.Add(new DataTable("liste")); dt["liste"].Columns.Add("Barcode"); dt["liste"].Columns.Add("UrunAd"); dt["liste"].Columns.Add("UrunFiyat"); dt["liste"].Columns.Add("UrunAdet"); dt["liste"].Columns.Add("GrupIsmi"); dt["liste"].Rows.Add("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");`

Comment: unfortunately it didn't happen again.